# return observable item on callback

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I need to `switchMap` an `Observables<Action>`:

```
this.actions$
    .ofType('LOAD_SOURCES')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      Stripe.card.createToken(
        <StripeCardTokenData>{name: "PLACEHOLDER NAME"},
        (status, response) {

        }
      )
);
```

where

```
private actions$: Actions;
class Actions extends Observable<Action> {...}
export interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
}
```

As you can see, the second parameter of `createToken` is a callback function I should handle. So, I don't know to return a new action when callback is reached since when it's called observable has passed.

The signature of the callback is:

```
createToken(data: StripeCardTokenData, responseHandler: (status: number, response: StripeCardTokenResponse) => void): void;
```

As you can see it reuturns `=> void`!

How could I create an Action item when callback is reached according the response data?

So the goal is to return another action (but when callback is reached:

```
this.actions$
    .ofType('ADD_SOURCE')
    .switchMap(
      (action: Action) => 
      (Observable.of({ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS' })));
```

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create an observable from all callback. If so, check out `bindCallback`. Here is a link to the documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback

For example:

```js
const log = (val, cb) => cb(val);
const trace = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(log);

trace('hello')
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. It looks fine. I've tried to use `Observable.bindCallBack`, but this method is not available. Do I need to import something?

Comment: If you did something like `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` the `bindCallback` should be available. Note *LOWER* "b"!

Comment: I've import it using `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`. Nevertheless thing method is not available. I'm using 5.2.0 version...

Comment: Though to say without knowing your setup and seeing your code. Who is telling you that the method is not available? TypeScript or runtime? I added an example to my question, what happens if you copy/paste that into your code base and remove the `Rx.`?

Comment: If you are importing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable`, you also need `import 'rxjs/add/observable/bindCallback';`